# $group by each unique string in MongoDb aggreagte

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have an buch of documents of events in MongoDB that I want to group by `createdAt`, and get a count each unique `title` for the event created the same day.

Event documents is like this:

```
{
   "createdAt": 2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z,
   "title": "Book meeting"
}
```

So far I get the output:

```
[{
        "titles": [
          "Book meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Personal meeting",
          "Personal meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Training",
          "Book meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Book meeting",
          "Digital meeting",
          "Support"
        ],
        "date": "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z"
}, ...events ],
```

But I want to it to be:

```
{
        "Book meeting": 10,
        "Digital meeting": 7,
        ...for all titles
        "date": "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z"
},
```

Here is what I am doing so far:

```
    Events.aggregate().group({
        _id: {
          createdAt: "$createdAt",
          title: "$title"
        }
      })
      .group({
        _id: {
          year: { $year: "$_id.createdAt" },
          month: { $month: "$_id.createdAt" },
          day: { $dayOfMonth: "$_id.createdAt" }
        },
        titles: { $push: "$_id.title" }
      })
      .project({
        _id: 0,
        date: {
          $dateToString: {
            date: {
              $dateFromParts: {
                year: "$_id.year",
                month: "$_id.month",
                day: "$_id.day"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        titles: 1,
      })
```

Comment: Can you add sample documents in json format to the question?

Comment: It consist of `createdAt` and `title`. That's it.

Comment: You had better to add to the question, it will help you get answers.

Comment: Added it to the question!

Comment: Is createdAt field string or ISODate?

Comment: It is ISODate !

Comment: Do you mean `titles: { $sum: 1 }` in order to get the count of titles?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit. No I want to get the count of each unique title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Events.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        title: "$title",
        date: {
          $dateToString: {
            date: "$createdAt",
            format: "%Y-%m-%d"
          }
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.date",
      titles: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.title",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      titles: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            "date": {
              $concat: [
                "$_id",
                "T00:00:00.000Z"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            $arrayToObject: "$titles"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$titles"
  }
]).exec();
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VO8oICQJACP)